# Updating app through fabric beta says "Do you want to uninstall this app?"

Tags: android, crashlytics-android, crashlytics-beta

I have published a new version of app through Fabric. I have signed the apk with same certificate as previous version. After open app from Beta ( by Crashlytics), when click "INSTALL UPDATE" for new version of app, it says "Do you want to uninstall this app?"

I am expecting the update app should proceed installation without this uninstall dialog. Why it is asking for uninstall previous version, although it is signed with same certificate?

Comment: I'm also encountering this issue, did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

This may be happening because the new app coming from Fabric Beta has a lower versionCode than the existing app running on the device. At least, that was the case for me.